# Prevent kendo tooltip hide/close when clicking outside the tooltip?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-tooltip

I know that there are people ask kendo to prevent kendo tooltip from close/hide whenever we click outside the tooltip. They are suggesting it [here](http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/127393-telerik-kendo-ui-feedback/suggestions/4526679-tooltip-hide-configuration-on-clicking-outside-too) but seems that it has not been implemented yet.

I couldn't find the method which closes/hides when we click outside kendo tooltip so far. I only found the event triggered when we click on close or cancel button on kendo tooltip. But is there any way/hackish way to achieve this using javascript/jquery/anything?

Comment: There is way for preventing hidding tooltip feature. In hide method of tooltip call show() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you see in link that you included the kendo tooltip (with `autoHide: false` property) hides when you:

- click outside the tooltip
- scroll page
- hit Esc

Until Telerik will not implement function to prevent it, the only way is using jquery `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`. For example for block tootlip from hide when you click outside you can write:

```
$("#target").kendoTooltip({
    autoHide: false
});
$('html').on('mousedown', function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Working demo: http://dojo.telerik.com/ugUCI

Unfortunately it will prevent **any** html onmousedown events like DropDownLists/ComboBoxes hiding etc.

Comment: that is the problem with e.stopImmediatePropagation() there will be bunch of problem appear

Answer (score 0):

You can override the close function of the kendo UI popup class to prevent execution. My solution was to throw a custom exception in the 'hide' handler and prevent the close from happening if this custom exception is caught.

```
kendo.ui.Popup.fn.close = function (close) {
    return function (skipeffects) {
        try {
            close.call(this, skipeffects);
        } catch (err) {
            // suppress error if its the right type
            if (!(err instanceof PreventTooltipHideException)) {
                throw err;
            }
        }
    }
}(kendo.ui.Popup.fn.close);


var tooltip = $('#' + areaId).kendoTooltip({
    content: "Hello World!",
    hide: function (e) {
         throw new PreventTooltipHideException();
    },
    autoHide: false
});
```